# Carousel React JS, JSON, JSX TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

Im at the beginning of react js, and im new here so sorry if I wrote the problem illegibly
I would like to do Carousel using JSON.Data but only i can display one photo, i can not do sliding photos.
I hope someone could help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjHLV.png)

data.json

```
   {
  "Slajd":[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "title",
        "image": [
           "https://cf.bstatic.com/images/hotel/max1024x768/263/263731269.jpg",
           "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"
        ]
   }
  ]
}
```

JSX

```
 import React from 'react';
import { Container, Carousel, CarouselItem, CarouselProps } from 'react-bootstrap';
export function Slider({ data }) {
    return(
             <Carousel>
                 <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
                 <img
                   className="d-block w-100"
                   src={data.image}
                   />
               </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        );
}
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return(
      <Container>
       {photo.Slajd.map(data => (
       <Carousel xs={3} key={data.id}>
         {data.image.map(imgSrc => (
        <Slider imgSrc={imgSrc}/>
         ))}
         </Carousel>
       ))}
      </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first tip, try to put `debugger` and see what `data` or `photo` JSON returns. You can do it with `console.log` as well.

Second, as I see you are looping through your slides, then looping through image URLs and passing that URL to the Slider component as `imgSrc` prop, but in the Slider component, you are trying to get `data` prop instead of `imgSrc`.

Try to change like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Carousel, CarouselItem, CarouselProps } from 'react-bootstrap';
export function Slider({ imgSrc }) {
    return(
             <Carousel>
                 <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
                 <img
                   className="d-block w-100"
                   src={imgSrc}
                   />
               </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick respond.
I did as you suggested. It is working but photos are showed one by one. This is still not a slider. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @LukaszxDunat You are declaring ```Carousel``` Component both in ```Slider``` and ```App``` components. Remove ```Carousel``` component from Slider, leave just a ```Carousel.Item```. You can wrap it in ```<> </>```. See this example https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/carousel/

Comment: I deleted Carousel component from Slider, but right now nothing is displayed.
Do i have to set active class item?